# Texture masking problem, wall becomes transparent under cracks?

Tags: materials, node-editor, transparency, masking

Hi I want to make a texture combining a plaster texture with an alpha-masked cracks/weathering texture. It works if I mix them but I don't want the cracks to be everywhere so I added a pointiness node to make the cracks only appear on top of the wall (or anywhere else where the pointiness masks the wall). I can't seem to work it out I've been trying for over an hour and I can't mask it without the plaster wall texture disappering from under the cracks where I masked it with the pointiness node.

See node setup and example screenshot to understand it better.[image: Wall becoming transparent under the cracks.]